# iis redirect a PDF URL to another url - Problem with spaces

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

A user has emailed a link to a pdf out to a number of users, instead of displaying this pdf I now want to display a webpage, the name of the pdf includes spaces, so its encoded like so:

```
https://www.mywebsite.net/Content/uploads/userUploads/Name%20of%20thisl%20bothersome%20Document.pdf
```

I've tried to redirect as below:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="redirectpdf" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^Content/uploads/userUploads/Name%20of%20thisl%20bothersome%20Document.pdf$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mywebsite.net/Article/52" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

In testing the pattern works:

[image]

Looks like the spaces in the document are causing an issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the string which is matched in the pattern is already Url-decoded, so you no need to use the %20 in your regex.

you could see the below-failed requests tracing log:

[image]

sample rule:

```
 <rule name="space rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/uploads/Name of this some Document.pdf" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.test.com" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: Again this rule passes in test but its not redirecting the link?

Comment: @Dez79 which link do you want to redirect. could you please explain in detail.

Comment: The current link to the document is: https://www.mywebsite.net/Content/uploads/userUploads/Name%20of%20Document.pdf - When soemone goes to this address i want to go to - www.test.com

Comment: @Dez79 try to run failed request tracing and share tracing results with us. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules